# does @jmslistener with same container factory share thread pool

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I have 2 jmsliteners setup like this in spring boot:

```
@EnableJms

@JmsListener(id= "A1", destination = "dest1", containerFactory = "factory1")
@JmsListener(id= "A2", destination = "dest2", containerFactory = "factory1") 
public void onMessage(String request) {
    //some processing
}

@Bean(name = "factory1")
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory){
 DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency("2-10");
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    jmsListenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return jmsListenerContainerFactory;
}
```

Since 2 jmslisteners have different id but share same containerFactory, does these 2 jmslisteners share a same thread pool?

I.E, if I have 100 messages at dest1 and 1 messages at dest2, is it possible that all thread available are going to be taken up by listener a1 , and listener a2 wont be able to run till most of messages at a1 are consumed?

Ideally these 2 shall run in parallel and I do not want to create some async future tasks in my processing.

Answer (score 5):

They are independent; by default they each use a separate `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

You can configure the factory with a `TaskExecutor` and the containers will use the same one, but, if it's a pooled executor, it must have enough threads to support the total max concurrency of all listeners.